# Considering alternatives to traditional on-prem fileserver

Tags: microsoft-office-365, file-sharing

I am considering alternative solutions for managing a smallish fileserver. Currently I look after (amongst other things) several small MS-Windows fileservers - in total around 4Tb of data supporting around 200 clients. To date, these have not not been well cared for, and I was looking to consolidate these into a single server with better capacity management and backup capability, but as we already have Office365 subscription with bundled storage, I am left wondering if there might be a better way of doing this.

Currrently the clients are almost exclusively MS-Windows boxes, but I also have similar sized NFS storage for Unix/Linux - consolidating these would be an added bonus.

My experience of MS-OneDrive is somewhat limited - all I have seen is an absence of hierarchical folders, and access control devolved to the end-user. The thought of letting my users choose their own access policy and dump hundreds of thousands of files into a single folder fills me with horror.

Is this the *only* way to use MS-onedrive? Can I set quotas? Directory hierarchies with ACLs? Is there any documentation for running a managed OneDrive installation, or is it just a marketing trap for ever escalating storage costs?

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive is personal storage for Office 365 users. It isn't shared between OneDrive users. So UserA doesn't natively have access to OneDrive data for UserB.

If you're referring to "company" shared data then you might look into using Sharepoint Online.

For individual users data, OneDrive is a perfectly acceptable solution.